# HQL is generating incomplete 'cross join' on executeUpdate

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, grails

I am working on a grails project. I have following query that I am trying to execute

```
String CHECK_FOR_HIGH_TRADE_VOLUME_QUERY = "Update LocationTrade lt set lt.hasVeryHighVolume=true where lt.locationIndices=? AND lt.trade.volume>20000";

...

LocationTrade.executeUpdate(CHECK_FOR_HIGH_TRADE_VOLUME_QUERY, [indices]);
```

The relationship between LocationTrade and Trade is unidirectional many-to-one. So, LocationTrade has a reference to Trade but Trade class does not have reference to the List of LocationTrade.

On execution, I get the following exception.

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not execute update query; SQL [update location_trade cross join  set has_very_high_volume=1 where location_indices_id=? and volume>20000]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute update query

and

Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'set has_very_high_volume=1 where location_indices_id=997 and volume>20000' at line 1
```

It seems that generated query is wrong. There should have been a join with the Trade table, but that is missing. I am unable to identify the error that I made here. Can some of you help me?

Creation Script for the two tables (I have stripped some of the uninteresting columns)

```
CREATE TABLE `location_trade` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `version` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `auto_status` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `exclusion_reason_description` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `exclusion_reason_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `exclusion_reason_title` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `location_indices_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `manual_status` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `trade_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `absolute_price` decimal(19,6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `flag` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `auto_exclusion_reason` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `exclusion_reason_text` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_updated` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `has_very_high_volume` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FK858985A90CAA966` (`location_indices_id`),
  KEY `FK858985AB5FA6A69` (`trade_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK858985A90CAA966` FOREIGN KEY (`location_indices_id`) REFERENCES `location_indices` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK858985AB5FA6A69` FOREIGN KEY (`trade_id`) REFERENCES `trade` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=25405 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;




CREATE TABLE `trade` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `version` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `comments` varchar(1020) DEFAULT NULL,
  `end_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `price` decimal(19,6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `price_type` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `source_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `start_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `trade_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `trade_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `volume` decimal(19,6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `volume_units` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_updated` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FK697F1642D085935` (`source_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK697F1642D085935` FOREIGN KEY (`source_id`) REFERENCES `job_source` (`id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=26567 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you add the `CREATE` statements for both tables?

Comment: @Declan_K added the create script

Comment: I finally went with Native SQL. My concern with Native SQL was that I did not want to start a new Transaction which got resolved here http://stackoverflow.com/q/16507369/593644

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The [Hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.2/manual/en-US/html_single/#batch-direct) says:

> No join, either implicit or explicit, can be specified in a bulk HQL query. Sub-queries can be used in the where-clause, where the subqueries themselves may contain joins.

`lt.trade.volume` is an implicit inner join between LocationTrade and Trade, so the query is invalid. You'll have to rewrite it to something like the following:

```
update LocationTrade lt set lt.hasVeryHighVolume=true where lt.locationIndices=? 
and lt.id in (
    select lt2.id from LocationTrade lt2 where lt2.trade.volume > 20000)
```

Or you'll have to use a SQL query instead.

Comment: I will try this out. But, I remember that MySQL does not allow 'UPDATE' of a table after selection.

Comment: Didn't work with MySQL

`SQLException: You can't specify target table 'location_trade' for update in FROM clause`

Comment: Then you'll have to use SQL I'm afraid.

Comment: This applies only to DML-style operations