# Grails: Raw SQL query in the current transaction

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm, grails-2.0

I am trying to execute a raw sql query using something similar to

```
def dataSource;
Sql sql = new Sql(dataSource);
```

But, it seems that this runs in a separate transaction of its own. It therefore misses all the (uncommitted) changes done before it in the service method.

What is the best way to run a raw sql query in the current transaction?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The above code would create a new connection, hence a new transaction. You can use the current Hibernate session(injecting sessionFactory) to execute a raw sql in the current transaction as below.

```
def session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
def results = session.createSQLQuery(yourQueryString)
```